# Woocommerce content after short description - why not shown to logged out users?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I try to add special content to woocommerce products that have a special tag.
I hook into the short description.

This I got to work fine. So I thought...

Now I see: The content is there all right as long as I am logged in. When viewed not logged in, I can't see anything of my special content. Seems that my code is executed only for logged in users/admin. But how can this be?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'EPREL_content', 10, 2);
function EPREL_content( $EPRELlabel ) {
    global $product;
    // Here define your specific product tag terms (can be Ids, slugs or names)
    $product_tags = array( 'EPREL' );

    if( has_term( $product_tags, 'product_tag', get_the_ID() ) ) {
        $EPRELlabel .= '<div class="custom_content"><a data-elementor-open-lightbox="yes" href=/EPREL/EUEVK_' . $product->get_sku() . '.png><img src="https://econlux.de/EPREL/G.svg" width="80px;" /></a><br /><a class="mini" target="_blank" href=/EPREL/EUEVK_' . $product->get_sku() . '.png.pdf>Produktdatenblatt</div>';
    }
    return $EPRELlabel;
}
```

The product to test is here:
https://econlux.de/produkt/solarstinger-nanoflex-fresh/

(only that you will not see any of the content, I fear)

I looks like that, when I am logged in:
[Screenshot of the extra content inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBuPg.png)

Can anyone hint me to why the code does not work for page visitors but works ok for me when logged in (admin user)?

Additional info in case it matters: I use YITH request a quote to hide prices and cart button and show qoute button instead. But this should not affect the short-description, should it? Anyway Prices are hidden from me when logged in too, but my extra content is shown.

Thank you very much,
nici-

Comment: Sounds like a cache issue. Clear your server-side cache and try again

Comment: Gosh, that is it. I wasn't aware there was a caching plugin active. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. it's absolutely working as expected. I have tested login/logout in both cases.

**Case 1**

Custom content for all products that have "EPREL" tag.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'EPREL_content', 20, 1);
function EPREL_content($post_excerpt) {
    global $product;
    $custom_text = '';
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    $product_tags = array( 'EPREL' );
   
    if( has_term( $product_tags, 'product_tag', $product_id) ) {
        $custom_text = '<div class="custom_content"><a data-elementor-open-lightbox="yes" href=/EPREL/EUEVK_' . $product->get_sku() . '.png><img src="https://econlux.de/EPREL/G.svg" width="80px;" /></a><br /><a class="mini" target="_blank" href=/EPREL/EUEVK_' . $product->get_sku() . '.png.pdf>Produktdatenblatt</div>';
        return $post_excerpt.'<br>'.$custom_text;
    }
    return $post_excerpt;
}
```

**Case 2**

Now you can add different "Custom content" for "variable products" and "other products" that have "EPREL" tag.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'EPREL_content', 20, 1);
function EPREL_content($post_excerpt) {
    global $product;
    $custom_text = '';
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    $product_tags = array( 'EPREL' );
   
    if( has_term( $product_tags, 'product_tag', $product_id) ) {
        if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            $custom_text = '<div class="custom_content">Dummy content for variable product.... </div>';
        }else{
            $custom_text = '<div class="custom_content">Dummy content for simple product.... </div>';
        }
        return $post_excerpt.'<br>'.$custom_text;
    }
    return $post_excerpt;
}
```

There is 2 case, you can choose one of them accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much, that looks elegant and works like a charm.

Unfortunately I just found out that there are some products with variants that need the labelling too. Now this blows my idea with the product tag plus product-ID is not variant-ID:
[link]https://econlux.de/produkt/solarstinger-sunstrip-35-fresh/[/link]

Do you have any idea on how I could build a function that works with variant products too? I am a bit lost now ;-(

Thank you very much!
nici-

Comment: Now I have updated my answer as per your above comment, so by using case 2, you can add a custom label for both types(variable, simple products) of products sepratly.

Comment: Add label according to product tyle, then should check this one - https://gist.githubusercontent.com/patrickgilmour/9d4a28b4a2f0c1dcecbf/raw/6bcc68a27ad543d5d02b0bd6c1b4c32d45d576fe/woocommerce-simple-or-variable.php

Comment: Hi Rajeev,
again Thank you so much!
Actually I already had an if/then inserted, but did not find out: 
1.) How can I stop the label to be shown twice in variant products
2.) Where do I get the variant SKU instead of product SKU from in variant product? 
I need the SKU to show the individual label for the chosen/shown variant. 

Background: Each individual variant product may have an individual label that I must show. I'd love to go by SKU for this as the SKU is the produuct ID that the merchant uses as identifier mostly.

But there is nothing like ->get_sku for $variation_data

Comment: I found several posts for variation sku here but must say, I am a bit lost: Some go with functions.php only, others with additional changes to the template. I understand, that the variant sku is not trivial, as I have to grab the selected variant by JS. Thus I wonder, if my basic idea of the logic (and the hook, as the label is printed twice in variable products) for everything makes sense anyway?
Best regards
nici-

Comment: Strange that there is no plugin for the EU Energy labels exept outdated ones ;-(

Comment: Sorry - had to set visibility to hidden as site is productive. But still there in page souce code: https://econlux.de/produkt/solarstinger-sunstrip-35-fresh/

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your requirement, So you can see this URL and update your login accordingly. https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-product-info-title-sku-desc-product-object/

Comment: If you want something else you can create a new questions also with proper detailing.